# Error in Writing HashMap to SQL Database - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, onclicklistener

Whenever I try to update my HashMap into my SQL database, my Android application keeps crashing. I do not know what is the issue with my application. Below is the method addProduct, which is supposed to add my value to the database and below it is the onClickListener where the add product is utilized. Is there any glaring issue with either code? Whenever I try to implement the following code, my app just crashes. (Note: addProduct is in a separate class titled "MyDBHandler" and the variable in the onClick "dbHandler" is an instance of this in its specific activity.

```
 public void addProduct(HashMap  <String,ArrayList <Item>> expenses){
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            for (String key: expenses.keySet()) {
                values.put(COLUMN_KEY, key);
                for (int i = 0; i < expenses.get(key).size(); i++){
                    ArrayList <Item> prods = expenses.get(key);
                    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, prods.get(i).id);
                    values.put(COLUMN_PRICE, prods.get(i).cost);
                    db.insert(TABLE_EXPENSES, null, values);
                    values.put(COLUMN_KEY, key);

                }
            }
        db.close();
        }
```

---

```
 bAddExp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View view){
                String account = sAccount.getSelectedItem().toString();
                double cost = Double.parseDouble( etCost.getText().toString());
                String expense = etExpense.getText().toString();
                ArrayList<Item> temp = MainActivity.expenselist.get(account);
                Item item = new Item (expense, cost);
                temp.add(item);
                MainActivity.expenselist.put(account,temp);
                dbHandler.addProduct(MainActivity.expenselist);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

        });
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: in order to located the crash point,need error message .by the way I think you need call values.clear() after insert.

Comment: the error message is ": E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "key": syntax error." I personally cannot find the error near this.  *An important thing to note is that key is not the unique primary key. That is in another variable "id" which I put on autoincrement

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my solution by sticking with ints and strings separately.